# Why does 'd3.select("svg") == d3.select("svg")' resolve to 'false'?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am just curious as to why `d3.select("svg") == d3.select("svg")` resolves to `false` and not `true`.

With D3 loaded in my browser (I tried chrome and FF), I typed that line into the console and it gave me that surprising result.

I used D3 version 5

The `html` body looks like this:

```
<body>
<svg></svg>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you expect another result?

Comment: They are the same selections after all. In fact, I assigned `a = d3.select("svg")` and `b = d3.select("svg")` and I for some reason I had sth like
`const foo = d3.local(); foo.set(a, 561); foo.get(b)   // wished this would be 561 but in actuality it's undefined`

Comment: Well, I think both might be instances of an object with the same information, but not the same objects

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, you should use `===` when comparing objects in JS. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/523647/1913185)

Comment: @technogeek1995 indeed, as a rule of thumb, one should always use `===` in JavasCript. However, in this case (comparing objects), it'd make no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56955139/5768908) provides an alternative (and the correct one by the way) to your problem. My goal here is to explain **why** you got the `false`.

This boils down to the old and famous case of comparing objects (`{} !== {}`) in JavaScript:

```js
console.log({} === {})
```

You can read more about this subject by looking at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1068834/5768908) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201183/5768908). The first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25139329/5768908) is also quite interesting and didactic.

Back to D3:

In D3 v3 and below selections are arrays, while in D3 v4 and above (like V5, the one you're using), selections are objects. Both will return `object` for `typeof`:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
console.log(typeof svg)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

And, in both cases (arrays or objects), the comparison will return `false`.

Because of that, even if two different selections point to the same DOM element, *the selections themselves, **which are objects**, are different*:

```js
const svg1 = d3.select("svg");
const svg2 = d3.select("svg")
console.log(svg1 === svg2)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Finally, regarding your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56955019/why-does-d3-selectsvg-d3-selectsvg-resolve-to-false#comment100448819_56955019), you're using the local variable wrong: you have to set it to the *node*, not to the selection. The [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#local_set) is clear:

> *local.set(node, value)* <>
>
> Sets the value of this local on the specified **node** to the value, and returns the specified value. (emphasis mine)

If you use it correctly, it will work:

```js
const a = d3.select("svg");
const b = d3.select("svg");
const local = d3.local();
local.set(a.node(), 561);
console.log(local.get(b.node()))
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks. Even though Aswin Kumars answer was helpful too, this post gives a good explanation from the bottom up.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`node()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_node)

`d3.select("svg")`        - return d3 selection object
`d3.select("svg").node()` - return DOM node

```js
console.log(d3.select("svg") == d3.select("svg"))

console.log(d3.select("svg").node() == d3.select("svg").node())
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.0.0-alpha.23.min.js"></script>

<svg></svg>
```