# Two identical objects are not equal? (Apparently)

Tags: javascript, node.js

BETTER ANSWERS [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-can-i-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)
They aren't equal because with objects js checks for the reference not the value.

I have an object in an array, and the array is iterated through, running a method on each of the elements (which are all the same class). In the method it tries to get the element's index in the array:
`const index = game.players.indexOf(this)`
This obviously should return the index, since no modifications to the element have been made (its one of the first lines in the method), however it returns `-1`

So I put in this line:
`console.log(game.players[0], this, game.players[0] == this)`
It gave me the two identical-looking objects, and `false`. I spent a couple minutes double and triple checking both objects for differences, eventually just searched up a text difference checker and...[the two objects are identical??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtbW6.png) (i included the whole objects incase anyone wanted to see them)
What???? is this some weird behind the scenes memory thing I dont know about?? I tried both `===` and `==`, both returned false.

Here is all the relevant code:

```
//iterating through the loop
for (let i in this.players) {
    let actionChance = 1
    while (Math.random() <= actionChance) {
        // run newAction() on each item
        result.push(this.players[i].newAction(this.players.length))
        actionChance *= 0.6
    }
}
```

```
newAction(players, round) {
    //getting the parent object which is iterating through the array and running this method
    const data = require('./data.json')
    //the game is saved to data.json as a string, and then i have a static method to convert the parsed object to an instance of the game class
    let game = Game.toGame(JSON.parse(data[this.gameID]))

    //get the index
    const index = game.players.indexOf(this)
```

Comment: Objects are not the same instance, even though their content might be identical. Keeping the above statement in mind, when you use `indexOf`, it checks for the reference of the object, **not its content**.

Comment: Javascript check for reference, not the content. They are stored in different locations in memory, so they are not the same, even though they both look identical

Comment: You will need to use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) with custom equality check

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are two objects with the same values not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22828341/why-are-two-objects-with-the-same-values-not-equal)

Comment: Two objects are never equal, unless they are the same object. I.e. given `const a = {}, b = {}`, `a === a` is `true`, but `a === b` is not. Since `indexOf` uses `===` for comparison, you cannot use it in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is likely due to the behavior of indexOf when used with objects in JavaScript, combined with how you're handling object deserialization from JSON.

When you use indexOf, it checks for the object's reference in memory, not the object's value or properties. Since objects in JavaScript are reference types, two objects with identical properties do not necessarily equal each other (i.e., **{} is not === to {}**) because they occupy different locations in memory.

In your case, game.players.indexOf(this) returns -1 because the this reference inside newAction does not strictly equal (===) any object in game.players. This discrepancy arises from how you recreate your game object:

```
let game = Game.toGame(JSON.parse(data[this.gameID]))
```

To work around this, you need a way to identify players that does not rely on object references. A common approach is to use a unique identifier (e.g., an **ID property**) for each player. You could then find the index based on this identifier instead of using indexOf directly on the object reference.

```
const index = game.players.findIndex(player => player.id === this.id);
```

This solution assumes you modify your Game.toGame method and player objects to include and handle unique IDs correctly. By comparing a property value (which is not affected by object reference issues), you can accurately find the index of this player in the game.players array

Comment: Smells like an AI related content. If this is the case please read: [temporary policy generative ai eg chatgpt is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned)

Comment: @mandy8055 I smell it too (and a new contributor), but hey, at least its the best answer here